# How can I play vs A.I. on a set difficulty on a random map?

Tags: starcraft-2

I use to play a lot of 2v2 and 3v3 with random people vs A.I. on hard or very hard slowly working my way towards the Supreme Command achievement.

But with Heart of the Swarm they changed it so that when you choose to play vs AI from the Matchmaking menu it sets the difficulty depending on how you preform vs A.I.

I do not want to play every other game vs Elite AI and some times I just want to relax a bit and only play vs Harder A.I. but I still don't care about what map I play on or with who as long as it counts towards my achievement.

**Is there a way of looking for vs A.I. games as it was before HotS where I can set my race and the difficulty and play 2v2 or 3v3 with random people on a random map?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.**

They changed the way match-making works, and it is no longer possible to select the difficulty of the AI you play against (other than perhaps going out of your way to find people who are currently up against the difficulty you want). Even switching back to Wings of Liberty mode will not let you use the old match-making.

You *can* make a custom map & open it to the public, or join a custom melee match, but this won't allow you to play on a random map, and it counts towards a different set of achievements.

Comment: This was what I sadly thought, but I had hope for there being a way.

Answer (score 4):

You can still create a custom game with AI in them.

[image]

push the create game button, add some AI and go for it!

Or, you can simply do the training games (found in Matchmaking > Training) at your preferred level.

Not sure how custom games count towards achievements, though.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, but that is not what I am looking for, edited my question to make it more clear.